Erhu glissando symbols in LilyPond
I have some problems with LilyPond.
In Chinese music, the symbols below are often used for glissandos:

In normal staff notation, these should look like the picture below:

Is it possible to use LilyPond to create sheet music with these symbols? If it's possible, how can I do this?

Update:
Thank you to Carl Witthoft for their answer below. But I still want to know:

Is it possible to make the bend to the front of the note like in the images above?
(Maybe something like \bendBefore?)

Is it possible to add an arrow at the end of the bend?



Related: Slurs with arrows for glissando-alikes in Lilypond, how to?

Related: Create a custom articulation in LilyPond

The  "falls and doits"  as described here   come close.  They produce curves but not the arrowhead.
Sample code:
c2\bendAfter #+4
  c2\bendAfter #-4
  c2\bendAfter #+6.5
  c2\bendAfter #-6.5
  c2\bendAfter #+8
  c2\bendAfter #-8

Produces

#EDIT
Hidden in the guitar tablature section are some commands which lead to arrowhead
bend-styles = {
  <>^"default"
  f'4\^ g'4\^ f'2

  <>^"'hold"
  \grace f'4\^ g'1\bendHold \^ g'1

  <>^"'pre-bend"
  \grace f'4\preBend \^ g'1\bendHold \^ g'1

  <>^"'pre-bend-hold"
  \grace f'4\preBendHold \^ g'1\bendHold \^ g'1\^ f'

  \bar "|."
}


If you have more particular needs, you could always open up a request at lilypond.org .
